# Convert OrderBy list of String raw query to jpa query

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, java-11

Table:

```
ID  Code
1   Health
2   Freeze
3   Phone
4   Phone
5   Health
6   Hot
```

Order by list of String raw query:

```
select * from table 
order by FIELD(Code, 'Health', 'Phone', 'Freeze', 'Hot')
```

I want to convert this **raw query to JPA query** but can't found any way to do it. Please help me!

Note: The enviroment I'm using

- MySQL version: 8.0.25
- Spring boot version 2.5
- Java 11

Update 1: The condition FIELD(Code, 'Health', 'Phone', 'Freeze', 'Hot') should be a list. I also want to pass a list when convert this raw query to JPA query

Update 2: Thanks to @TimBiegeleisen answer and comment I realize that JPA is not suitable for my problem.

Comment: You can't convert a Java list of strings into the `CASE` expression you'll need in your JPA query.  A JPA query is backed by a prepared statement, and the structure of the query (but not the literal values) must be hard coded and fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FIELD` expression you have, particular to MySQL, can be rewritten in ANSI SQL using a `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Code = 'Health' THEN 1
              WHEN Code = 'Phone'  THEN 2
              WHEN Code = 'Freeze' THEN 3
              WHEN Code = 'Hot'    THEN 4 END
```

We can use the following JPA query:

```
SELECT e, (CASE WHEN e.Code = 'Health' THEN 1
                WHEN e.Code = 'Phone'  THEN 2
                WHEN e.Code = 'Freeze' THEN 3
                WHEN e.Code = 'Hot'    THEN 4 END) AS ord
FROM Entity e
ORDER BY ord
```

As I mentioned in the comments above, you will need a fixed `CASE` expression here.  You can't convert a Java list of strings into the CASE expression you'll need in your JPA query. A JPA query is backed by a prepared statement, and the structure of the query (but not the literal values) must be hard coded and fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry my question missing some information: the condition 'Health', .... should be a list, not fix condition like this. I will edit the question!!